# Ruby for Rails: underfined method 'name ' for #<Array:0xb6c971cc>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display the column 'name' after being found from the table mytest.

In the mytest.rb, I defined "attrib_accessor :name";

In the procedure index under directory /controller/mytest_controller.rb,

```
def index
###[Ignore some code]
@mytesttbl=@user.find_by_id 
### I am able to verify the tuples in @mytesttbl
end
```

In the /view/mytest/index.rhtml, I have code like

```
<div id="mytesttable"> <%= render(:partial =>"mytesttbl", :object => @mytesttbl)%> </div>
```

In the /view/mytest/_mytesttbl.html.erb. I have code like

```
<tr>
 <td><%=mytestbl.name %></td>
<tr>
```

when I ran the above code, I have error on _mytesttbl.html.erb,

```
undefined method 'name ' for #<Array:0xb6c971cc>
```

Please help. Thanks,

Comment: I think you should copy and paste the relevant code and explain a bit more. It is hard to figure out what is going on with all the typos. For example, what does the @user.find_by_id method return?

Comment: Is the controller code correct? find_by_id should give an error if you don't pass in a value. You can also try outputting @mytesttbl in your view to see exactly what it contains `<%= @mytesttbl.inspect %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that's not your actual code since it wouldn't actually work. Your `find` is returning an array. You either want to loop through the array or, if you know it contains only one object (as in the case where you actually are finding by a unique id), you can just do `mytesttbl.first` to get the object out of it.

Comment: Hi, I tried to loop to publish the names in the array with your suggestion. I replaced the code in mytesttbl.html.erb as below, In the /view/mytest/_mytesttbl.html.erb. I have code like <tr>  <td><%=obj.name %></td>  <tr> I got error, "undefined local variable or method `obj' for #<ActionView::Base:0xb6c9f930>". What is the wrong? Thx,

Comment: @erwin: You don't have a variable named "obj".

Comment: I used the code below. How to pass the obj to _mytesttbl.html.erb? thx

<% @mytesttbl.each do |obj| %>
  <div id="mytesttable">
   <%= render(:partial =>"mytesttbl", :object => @obj)%>
  </div>
<% end %>

Comment: Then your variable in partial is called `object`, not `obj`. You can also use `<%= render :partial => 'mytesttbl', :collection => @mytesttbl %>`. Your object will have name `mytesttbl` in partial code (it the name of a partial).

Comment: Actually, I think the variable would be called `mytesttbl`, since the `:object` parameter translates into a variable named after the partial.

Comment: Hi, thx for your replies. I replaced ":object=>@mytesttbl" with ":collection=>@mytesttbl" in index.rhtml, there was not compiling error, but instead of displaying the names in the web browser, the _mytesttbl.html.erb showed the same number of EMPTY line as the number of name in the @mytesttbl. I was able to use 'puts' to verify the name in console. Why were the names not shown in web browser from _mytesttbl.html.erb? thx

Comment: Thanks for your help. 

I found out that 'attr_accessor :name' in /model/mytest.rb caused the problem. Once I removed that line of statement, the "name" was showned on the web browser. I donot know why?

Answer (score 1):

`mytesttbl` is an `array`. Change `view/mytest/index.rhtml` to

```
<% @mytesttbl.each do |obj| %>
  <div id="mytesttable">
   <%= render(:partial =>"mytesttbl", :object => obj)%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Edit: Also,  `view/mytest/_mytesttbl.html.erb` should look like

```
<tr>
 <td><%= object.name %></td>
<tr>
```

Comment: Hi, I replaced the code in mytesttbl.html.erb as below,
In the /view/mytest/_mytesttbl.html.erb. I have code like

    <tr>
      <td><%=obj.name %></td>
    <tr>


I got error, "undefined local variable or method `obj' for #<ActionView::Base:0xb6c9f930>"

Comment: Does it really work like that? I'd expect it to need "each do |@obj|"

Comment: ** Trevoke ** I think it should be :object => obj not @obj

Comment: Hi, thx for your replies. I tried with/out  @ in index.rhtml, the "obj" is not defined in _mytesttbl.html.erb. It reported the same error.

Comment: @erwin: Try the updated code and please do make sure that you understand what was wrong with your version of it.

Comment: It works now. I found out that using :collection can remove the loop from the suggestion above. Here is a good reference for using render. Thanks again, you guys are awesome. 

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Answer (score 0):

arent you missing an argument for the @user.find_by_id? usually when i want to get the name i do:

controller
@user= User.find(params[:id]) to find a user by a specific id.

view

if you want to find all users then

controller 
@user = User.find(:all)

view

User.find_by_id is redudant because User.find by default finds by id.